Equivalent idioms for "Throw me a bone"
The phrase "throw me a bone" is now forever linked to Dr. Evil (Mike Myers). Are there any equivalent idioms or common modern slang that I can use for a comedy bit? Being literal, like "Will someone please help me out here?" wouldn't be as funny as a good idiom.
(I would've posted this to English Language and Usage but they make a point of the site being pretty much purely for linguists and language enthusiasts and suggested questions by other folks be put on other sites, like "Writing")

Who?  I'm familiar with the idiom but you may be overestimating the association.

I don't understand why English.SE reject this question. It seem a better fit there than here to me. They have a special tag for idioms and many (i.e., thousands) of similar questions. Here, this is a what-to-write question and off topic, in my opinion. I therefore vote to close.

How about:
"cut me some slack here,"
"give me a break,"
"bail me out on this one,"
"lend me a hand here,"
"do me a solid."

Deconstructing "throw me a bone", the speaker is making an exaggerated plea while simultaneously setting the bar surprisingly low, so low they are  dog. It creates a disorienting irony in the listener, they adjust, then adjust again in a different direction.
"You could knock me over with a feather" is a similar exaggeration that becomes funnier as the listener stops to imagine it literally. It is a very specific image.
In both cases the idiom speaks from self-depreciation – it's a 'safe' target for the joke. The listener has to adjust to the POV, before they can understand the meaning.
In comedy, a paraprosdokian is a sentence or statement with an unexpected ending. It feels like it's going in one direction, but it ends with a different meaning. I encountered a panhandler with an ironic plea, "Could somebody hit me in the head with a quarter?"
As an anti-example, Paul Verhoeven's Robocop invented a catchphrase for a sleazy TV personality "I'd buy THAT for a dollar!" The dichotomy is showing enthusiasm by making a financial offer, but the amount is symbolic, a token to make the contract legal. The reversal is hollow praise from the POV of a low-risk hypeman.

Lots of good info here. Thank you very much!
